# Convergence of a series involving logs $\sum_{n=2}^{\infty} \frac{\ln(\frac{n}{n+1})}{\ln(n)^2}$

Tags: sequences-and-series

I am working on showing the convergence of the series $\sum_{n=2}^{\infty} \frac{\sin(nx)}{\ln(n)}$ and have reduced the problem to showing that $\sum_{n=2}^{\infty} \frac{\ln(\frac{n}{n+1})}{\ln(n)^2}$ converges. I have a hunch that it does converge, but am having trouble manipulating it to something I can apply the comparison test to. Hints to get me started are appreciated.

Comment: You should use that $- \ln(n/(n+1)) =\ln(1+1/n) \sim 1/n$.

Comment: Could you write down how did you reduce the series from first form to the second one?

Comment: In the denominator, is it the log squared or the log of the square?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Supposing the denominator is the log squared, we can use *equivalence*:
$$\frac{\ln(\dfrac{n}{n+1})}{\ln^2 n}=-\frac{\ln\Bigl(1+\dfrac1{n}\Bigr)}{\ln^2 n}\sim_\infty-\frac{\dfrac1{n}}{\ln^2n}=-\frac{1}{n\,\ln^2 n},$$
which is *Bertrand's series*.

This Bertrand's series converges by the integral test.